# Using NUnit to test for any type of exception

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have a class that creates a file.

I am now doing integration tests to make sure the class is ok.

I am passing in invalid directory and file names to make sure exceptions are thrown.

In my tests are I am using:

```
[Test]
public void CreateFile_InvalidFileName_ThrowsException()
{
    //Arrange
    var logger = SetupLogger("?\\");

    //Act

    //Assert
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(()=> logger.CreateFile());
 }
```

However in this scenario the test is failing as an `ArgumentException` is thrown. I thought by adding just `Exception` it would pass.

Is there a way to make this pass just using `Exception`?

Comment: One reason why it would be a good idea to test for a specific exception is that clients of the logger will probably want to avoid having to catch the base `Exception` class, and will therefore rely on a particular exception being thrown, so that's what you should test for.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The help for `Assert.Throws<>` states that it "Verifies a delegate throws a particular type of exception when called"

Try the `Assert.That` version as it will catch any `Exception`:

```cs
private class Thrower
{
    public void ThrowAE() { throw new ArgumentException(); }
}

[Test]
public void ThrowETest()
{
    var t = new Thrower();
    Assert.That(() => t.ThrowAE(), Throws.Exception);
}
```

Comment: +1 as this actually answers the question, but don't ignore the good advice in other answers to test for specific exceptions.

Comment: If you need to check exception properties or type later you can do: `var ex = Assert.Throws(Is.AssignableTo(typeof(Exception)), () => DoSomething());`

Comment: Using Nunit 3.6.1, I found that this answer doesn't work for me, but the answer by Adam Butler did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48696428/1384748

Answer (score 19):

For NUnit 2.5 and above

```
// Allow both ApplicationException and any derived type
Assert.Catch<ApplicationException>(() => logger.CreateFile());

// Allow any kind of exception
Assert.Catch(() => logger.CreateFile());
```

Comment: `Assert.Catch<T>` solves the asked question to-the-dot *and*, like `Assert.Throw<T>`, allows one to obtain the Exception as a result: `var ex = Assert.Catch<ApplicationException>(() => ..); AssertMoreOnException(ex);`.

Answer (score 6):

Throws.InstanceOf() allows you to pass a base exception type, instead of a more specific derived type.

```
[Test]
public void CreateFile_InvalidFileName_ThrowsException()
{
    //Arrange
    var logger = SetupLogger("?\\");

    //Act

    //Assert
    Assert.That(() => logger.CreateFile(), Throws.InstanceOf<Exception>());
}
```

Comment: I think readability-wise, this is the best answer. In my case, during my prototyping, I don't need to catch specific exception. On a later stage, when I refine my coding, I would change it to catch more specific exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your exceptions should be deterministic, and you should be able to write test cases that set up conditions under which a specific exception will be thrown, and you should test for that specific exception.

Thus, your test should be rewritten as

```
CreateFile_InvalidFileName_ThrowsArgumentException
```

and

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => logger.CreateFile());
```

Edit:

By the way, I think your constructor should be detecting invalid file names and throwing there. And then it should be a contract for the constructor that the file name is valid.

Comment: I agree but there are many odd things to think of and many exceptions likely to be thrown when creating files. I wonder if there are any pre-written integration tests already for this type of scenario

Comment: +1 As even though you don't answer the question, I agree with this advice. The types of exception your class throws form part of it's public API, and so should be tested.

Comment: @Jon, agreed it is a pain with the number of different types of exceptions that can be thrown by certain methods in the BCL. If your logger class wanted to be friendlier, it could catch those exceptions and throw a single exception (or at least fewer exceptions) wrapping the original as an inner exception. You'd then want to test for that exception explicitly in your automated tests.

Comment: You are a bit preachy which is annoying. None-the-less, I generally follow your guidelines. But, for every rule there are exceptions (no pun intended). One case where I want to catch a more general error (often Exception) is when i know my method under test calls another class' method that throws. Of course, the secondary class should be mocked/injected, but it's not always. Consider a simple parser (something often not injected) and it throws for invalid input. I want my test to propagate the exception, but I don't want my test to depend on which exception type the other class throws.

Answer (score 1):

You can tag your test method with the attribute `ExpectedException`. That should work.

```
   [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception))]
    public void TestException()
    {

    }
```

Comment: After reading Roy Osherove's book I try not to use the attributes

Comment: Interesting, I've read pragmatic unit testing and they encourage using attributes (And I personally use them too). Care to elaborate why not to use them? I'd be happy about a link or blog.

Comment: I can't find it in the book now so maybe it was his TDD course http://tekpub.com/productions/tdd

Comment: Thank you - I'll have a look.

Comment: @Alex One disadvantage of using the ExpectedException attribute is that you can't tell if the exception was thrown in the 'arrange' part rather than the 'act' part. That's why we stopped using them in our team.

Comment: @Alex - The problem with this attribute is that you don't know which line threw the exception. With the Assert. syntax the 'Arrange' portion of the test won't trigger a false result as you are only looking for the Exception during the 'Act/Assert' portion.

Comment: Good points, guess its a matter of how small the test method is to obviously point out which line threw it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you should only test specific exceptions to make sure your code is responding properly to different errors.

If you really need to allow **any** exception for the sake of your test, just use a standard try/catch block and normal Success/Failure asserts.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own method and use that for validation.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Throwses the specified action.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="action">The action.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Throws<T>(Action action) where T : Exception
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (T ex)
        {
            return ex;
        }

        Assert.Fail("Expected exception of type {0}.", typeof(T));
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This seems to do what Assert.That(() => ..., Throws.extype) does.